# Is there any way to parse HTML from HTTP GET request using ELK?

Tags: filebeat, elk, metricbeat

I'm started using ELK stack and met a problem. I have some web-service that can give some values via HTTP API, but this values are in HTML format response. I tried to use metricbeat with http module, but it can only parse JSON format. Main idea is to send periodic GET requests like http://127.0.0.1:8090/stats/, parse HTML response data and send it to logstash. I google'd it and find no answers. Is there any way to do that with internal beats instruments? If not, can you suggest me in what direction should I dig?

Thanks!